# How to find encrypted pass in Bamboo?

Tags: encryption, passwords, bamboo

I have a pipeline in Bamboo with encrypted secret access key which is masked by ******.

How do I find out what is the real password?

I am very new in Bamboo, please give me the answer with more details.

Comment: Some hacks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59607672/access-bamboo-secret-password-variable). Bamboo should have some admin view to configure these secrets, though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access Bamboo secret/password variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59607672/access-bamboo-secret-password-variable)